# What is -s option in sqlplus used for?

Tags: shell, sqlplus

Am little new to shell script and would like to know the use of -s option [sqlplus -s] in shell script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not actually a shell question. Command-line arguments behave the same way on any kind of invocation, even with no command involved: You could pass a literal argument array from C (ie. `execvp("sqlplus", {"sqlplus", "-s", NULL})`), from Python (ie. `subprocess.Popen(["sqlplus", "-s"], shell=False)`), or pretty much any other language and get the exact same behavior with no shell involved in any way.

Comment: err, "even with no shell involved"

Comment: Noted. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm#1006198):

> -S[ILENT]
>
> Suppresses all SQL*Plus information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner normally displayed when you start SQL*Plus. If you omit username or password, SQL*Plus prompts for them, but the prompts are not visible. Use SILENT to invoke SQL*Plus within another program so that the use of SQL*Plus is invisible to the user.
>
> SILENT is a useful mode for creating reports for the web using the SQLPLUS -MARKUP command inside a CGI script or operating system script. The SQL*Plus banner and prompts are suppressed and do not appear in reports created using the SILENT option.

Comment: Thanks Charles. It was helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks again. This is my first question on stackoverflow. Very satisfied on how quickly it got answered. Tried to upvote but it seems I can't because of my low[none] reputation. Keep up the good work!!

Comment: Caveat: [What we consider a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) generally includes some evidence of having done your own research before asking. This friendly an answer for a question where such is not in evidence is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the advice :)